# How to calculate standard deviation cone around expected returns?

Tags: volatility, returns, standard-deviation, performance

I would like to evaluate the returns of an investment manager who has given me their return and volatility expectations for their fund. I would like to calculate both 1 and 2 standard deviations from what is expected. The chart below by Bridgewater Associates is what I am trying to replicate.

[image]

Comment: @noob2 Would you convert the comments to an answer so that I can properly upvote =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returns (or rather alphas, i.e. returns relative to the benchmark) plotted are *logarithmic returns*, not the simple returns usually reported by investment managers. This makes them additive over time.

The green line is a straight line with slope 18% (the expected annual alpha). The thin purple curve is $\sigma \sqrt{t}$ above and below the green line, where t is the time in years since inception. The thick purple curve is twice as far from the green line, i.e. $\pm 2 \sigma \sqrt{t}$ from the line. And $\sigma$, the annual standard deviation, is also 18%.

[The chart itself looks quite impressive, I did not know that Bridgewater had such good performance over this period. I wonder how it has done since then].

Comment: It is impressive. I know they've struggled over the past few years but with over $100B it becomes quite difficult.

Comment: How would you convert this to geometric returns? Would you need to concern yourself with volatility drag?